# Capistrano error : "could not connect to ssh-agent: Agent not configured"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, deployment, capistrano

I would like to deploy my app using capistrano.

I'm able to connect to the server using `ssh my_app_stag`, but when I try to `docker-compose run web cap staging deploy` I get this error :

> > D, [2018-09-21T11:46:40.858453 #1] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[ac989c]: connecting to ssh-agent
> >
> > E, [2018-09-21T11:46:40.858662 #1] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[ac989c]: could not connect to ssh-agent: Agent not configured
> >
> > E, [2018-09-21T11:46:40.859037 #1] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3f9c0e0cac1c]: all authorization methods failed (tried publickey)
> >     (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
> >     cap aborted!
> >
> > SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@34.244.167.85: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@34.244.167.85
> >
> > Caused by:
> >     Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@34.244.167.85
> >
> > Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
> >     (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I'm using pem key to authenticate, which is located in `.ssh/app_name.pem` (this key was included on the repo when I cloned the app. So I did not generate it my self)

**ssh/config**

```
Host my_app_stag
  ForwardAgent yes

  Hostname my_Ip_adress

  User ubuntu

  IdentityFile /Users/my_name/.ssh/app_name.pem
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.10.0'

set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.3'

set :default_stage,   'staging'
set :stages,          %w(staging production)

set :application, 'app_name'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:my_account/app_name.git'
set :full_app_name, "#{fetch(:application)}"

set :user,   'ubuntu'
set :use_sudo,        false

# Default branch is :master
set :branch,    fetch(:branch, "master")

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/apps/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :ssh_options, {
    auth_methods: %w[publickey],
  keys: %w(~/.ssh/app_name.pem),
  :verbose => :debug
}
set :use_agent, false
set :pty, true

[]).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/unicorn_init.sh config/unicorn.rb log/session.secret}

set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids public/assets public/images/promotions public/images/logo public/images/offers public/images/vehicules public/import_logs sitemaps}

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

set :bundle_bins, %w{gem rake ruby}

set(:config_files, %w(
  nginx.conf
  database.yml
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
))

set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"
  }
])

# set :linked_dirs, %w(public/system log tmp)
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
```

**staging.rb**

```
server 'ip_server', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w(app db web), primary: true

set :stage, :staging
set :rails_env, 'staging'
set :branch, 'develop'
```

I tried this [article](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add your ssh-key to a ssh-agent instead of linking to the file?

```
ssh-add -K /Users/my_name/.ssh/app_name.pem
```